# Data binding failing when passing variables to the viewmodel

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, maui, viewmodel

I have a UI with a name picker, a data picker, a button and some labels When the button is pressed i use the selected name to get a bunch of data from a database. I then want to use a viewmodel to calculate the numbers and return sunrise and sunset times through binding variables to my UI.

Using breakpoints I can see that it is all working and the label binding gets the text momentarily until  I step on in the debug. I've tried:

1. Passing the variables inside the proceedure brackets
2. Setting up binding variables in the vm and setting the values from the xaml.cs

Sunrise.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MrDiver.Views.Sunrise"
             BackgroundColor="LightYellow"
             Title="Sunrise/Sunset"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MrDiver.ViewModel">
    
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:SunViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <VerticalStackLayout
    Spacing="10"
    Margin="20"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    BackgroundColor="LightCoral"
    >

        <Label 
        Scale="0.9"
        Text="Sunrise / Sunset CALCULATOR"
        FontSize="Large"
        TextColor="White"
        FontAttributes="Bold"
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center" 
        />

        <Picker 
        Scale="0.9"
        BackgroundColor="LightGray" 
        Title="Select town and date" 
        TitleColor="White" 
        FontAttributes="Italic" 
        TextColor="Black" 
        FontSize="Medium" 
        x:Name="myTownPickerView"/>

        <DatePicker 
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        Scale="0.9"
        BackgroundColor="LightGray" 
        FontAttributes="Italic" 
        TextColor="Black" 
        FontAutoScalingEnabled="True" 
        x:Name="TownDate"/>

        <Button 
        Scale="0.9"
        BorderWidth="5"
        Text="Submit" 
        FontSize="Title" 
        FontAttributes="Bold" 
        x:Name="TownSubmit"  
        Clicked="OnButtonClicked" />

        <Label 
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        Text="MY Label" 
        x:Name="mylabel"></Label>

        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Sunrise "></Label>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding MySunriseBinding}"></Label>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Sunset "></Label>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding MySunsetBinding}"></Label>

        </Grid>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Sunrise.xaml.cs

```
 async void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        // Does a fancy rotate
        await mylabel.RelRotateTo(360, 1000);

        //Get the Town detail from the table
        var townID = 1 + (Int32.Parse(myTownPickerView.SelectedIndex.ToString()));
        PortDatabase portDatabase = new PortDatabase();
        var listatown = portDatabase.TownName(townID).Result;

        // Gets the town name, Lon and Lat into variables
        int selectedIndex = myTownPickerView.SelectedIndex;
        String townName = myTownPickerView.Items[selectedIndex];
        Double townLat = (double)listatown[0].Latitude;
        Double townLong = (double)listatown[0].Longitude;
        int zeneth = 91;
        int daylightSaving = 0;

        // Gets the selected date
        DateTime selectDate = TownDate.Date;

        // Displays the name, latitude and longitude
        mylabel.Text = townName + "  Lat:" + townLat + "  Long:" + townLong;

        //Get the surise sunset time
        SunViewModel sunViewModel = new SunViewModel();
        sunViewModel.zenith = 90;
        sunViewModel.Todaydate = selectDate;
        sunViewModel.Longdeg = townLong;
        sunViewModel.Latdeg = townLat;
        sunViewModel.SunriseModel();


}
```

SunViewModel.cs

```
public class SunViewModel : ContentView
{
   
    public string MySunriseBinding { get; set; }
    public string MySunsetBinding { get; set; }
    public DateTime Todaydate { get; set; }
    public Double Longdeg { get; set; }
    public Double Latdeg { get; set; }
    public int zenith {  get; set; }
    public int daylightsaving { get; set; }



    public double PI_BY_180 = 0.017453293;
    public SunViewModel()
    {
        MySunriseBinding = "";
        MySunsetBinding = "";

    }

    public void SunriseModel()
    {
        // a mess of calculations finishing with...

        MySunriseBinding = MySunrise;
        MySunsetBinding = MySunset;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code with a simulated calculation to try and reproduce the binding problem. As I understand it, clicking the [Submit] button should perform some calculations and ultimately update the values for Sunrise and Sunset. For example.

[image: sim]

Reading your code carefully, it appears that there may be some misunderstanding around the instantiation of `SunViewModel`. You seem to be on the right track with this block in your **xaml** file correctly instantiates a `SunViewModel` object and sets it as the binding context for the view.

```xml
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:SunViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

You can demonstrate that this is working correctly by adding this line to your `MainPage` constructor

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{        
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // This shows that the binding context is already set.
        Debug.Assert(
            base.BindingContext is MrDiver.ViewModel.SunViewModel,
            "Expecting BindingContext has already been set by Xaml");
    }
}
```

---

**What the problem might be**

One issue is that your `OnButtonClicked` method creates a *new* instance of `SunViewModel` that isn't really bound to anything at all.

```
async void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    .
    .
    .
    // This is probably not what you're intending to do.
    SunViewModel sunViewModel = new SunViewModel();
    sunViewModel.zenith = 90;
    sunViewModel.Todaydate = selectDate;
    sunViewModel.Longdeg = townLong;
    sunViewModel.Latdeg = townLat;
    sunViewModel.SunriseModel();
}
```

---

**Solution**

When the button is clicked, it needs to act on the instance of `SunViewModel` that is already bound to the view. It's fine how you're handling the `Clicked` event, but it would be a little more direct to put the command into the ViewModel so that it has ready access to the properties it needs.

```
class SunViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public SunViewModel()
    {
        ButtonClickedCommand = new Command(OnButtonClicked);
    }
    public ICommand ButtonClickedCommand { get; private set; }
    private void OnButtonClicked(object o)
    {
        // Simulate this method by randomizing times that are
        // up to an hour before 6 AM and up to an hour after 6 PM.
        int sunriseOffsetMinutes = _rando.Next(0, 61);
        MySunriseBinding = new DateTime(dateOnly.Year, dateOnly.Month, dateOnly.Day, 6, 0, 0)
                            .AddMinutes(-sunriseOffsetMinutes);
        int sunsetOffsetMinutes = _rando.Next(0, 61); 
        MySunsetBinding = new DateTime(dateOnly.Year, dateOnly.Month, dateOnly.Day, 18, 0, 0)
                            .AddMinutes(sunsetOffsetMinutes);

    }
    Random _rando = new Random();
    private static DateOnly dateOnly => new DateOnly(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Day);
    public DateTime MySunriseBinding
    {
        get => _mySunriseBinding;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_mySunriseBinding, value))
            {
                _mySunriseBinding = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    DateTime _mySunriseBinding = new DateTime(dateOnly, new TimeOnly(6, 0));

    public DateTime MySunsetBinding
    {
        get => _mySunsetBinding;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_mySunsetBinding, value))
            {
                _mySunsetBinding = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    DateTime _mySunsetBinding = new DateTime(dateOnly, new TimeOnly(18, 0));


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string? propertyName = null)=>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

---

The only thing that needs to be different in the **xaml** is to bind the Command instead of the `Clicked` event:

```xml
<Button 
    Scale="0.9"
    BorderWidth="5"
    Text="Submit" 
    FontSize="Title" 
    FontAttributes="Bold" 
    x:Name="TownSubmit"  
    Command="{Binding ButtonClickedCommand}" />
```

Comment: It's definitely MAUI, you can tell by the namespace used in the XAML

Comment: A big thank you IV. I've learnt a lot from your example and everthing is working now. If I read this right binding only works in a  : ContentView Class if another procedure is called or the variable are changed within the procedure with the same name as the public class. As you showed the best method is by moving all the heavy lifting to the vm. In the XAML I've used binding for the picker with SelectedIndex="{Binding TownID, Mode=OneWayToSource}". The date picker has Date="{Binding Todaydate}".  From there it was straight forward. Thanks again.